# Unable to trigger UITableView Delegate Method "DidSelectRowAtIndexPath"

Tags: objective-c, ios, didselectrowatindexpath, uitableview

Hi I am using a `searchDisplayController` to filter through my search results. My code snippet is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Set up search bar
    UISearchBar *tempBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];
    self.sBar = tempBar;
    [tempBar release];
    self.sBar.delegate = self;
    self.sBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#b6c0c7"];
    self.sBar.placeholder = @"Search Questions and Topics";

    [self.view addSubview:sBar];

    self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.listContent count]];

    self.searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:sBar contentsController:self];
    [self setSearchDisplayController:searchDisplayController];
    [searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
    [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];

// restore search settings if they were saved in didReceiveMemoryWarning.
    if (self.savedSearchTerm)
    {
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:self.searchWasActive];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:savedSearchTerm];

        self.savedSearchTerm = nil;
    }

    [self.resultTableView reloadData];
    self.resultTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"zzz");
}
```

Do I need to setup anything in my view did load to trigger the uitable delegate method?

Note that I have already declared `UISearchDisplayDelegate`, `UISearchBarDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate` in my .h files. Also my `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you actually set

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

or connected it up in Interface Builder

Comment: this is right, and also make sure you are putting `<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>` in your .h file

Comment: Thanks! But where would be the best place to set the delegate? In View did load? In my case it would be self.resultTableView.delegate = self